# python bug in spell checker using binary search

Tags: python, spell-checking

i wrote the following code for a spell checker using binary search in python and it works properly but the output is inverse .. for example i wrote "hwllo world" and the output was world hello whereas it's to be "hello world"

my code is as follows :

```
    import difflib
    #L=[]
    ch=[]
    def binarySearch(alist, item):
            first = 0
            last = len(alist) - 1
            while first <= last:
                midpoint = (first + last) // 2
                if alist[midpoint] == item:
                   return True
                else:
                  if item < alist[midpoint]:
                     last = midpoint - 1
                else:
                     first = midpoint + 1
           return False

    f = open('wordlist.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
    v=str(input("enter your sentence : ")).split()


    for i in range(len(v)):
       if binarySearch(f, v[i]) == True:
          ch.append(v[i])


       elif binarySearch(f, v[i]) == False:
          sugg = []
          for word in f:
             if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, v[i], word).ratio() >= 0.8:
               sugg.append(word)
          print(sugg)

    for j in range (len(sugg)):
          print( "if you mean ",(sugg[j]),"press",(j))

    x=int(input())
    ch.append(sugg[x])

    print (' '.join(ch))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic because you're adding all the suggestions at the end rather than as you find misspelled words.

Instead of:

```
for i in range(len(v)):
   if binarySearch(f, v[i]) == True:
      ch.append(v[i])
   elif binarySearch(f, v[i]) == False:
      sugg = []
      for word in f:
         if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, v[i], word).ratio() >= 0.8:
           sugg.append(word)
      print(sugg)

for j in range (len(sugg)):
      print( "if you mean ",(sugg[j]),"press",(j))

x=int(input())
ch.append(sugg[x])
```

Try:

```
for i in range(len(v)):
   if binarySearch(f, v[i]):
      ch.append(v[i])
   elif not binarySearch(f, v[i]):
      sugg = []
      for word in f:
         if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, v[i], word).ratio() >= 0.8:
           sugg.append(word)
      print(sugg)

      for j in range (len(sugg)):
          print( "if you mean ",(sugg[j]),"press",(j))

      x=int(input())
      ch.append(sugg[x])
```